# onClickListener get external objects

Tags: java, android

I'm changing the background button when user clicks.

But I need change the background of 2 buttons: when I click in btnSim I need change the btnSim background and btnNao Background:

```
holder.btnNao.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        ImageButton botao = (ImageButton) arg0;

        if (botao.getBackground().getConstantState()==getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rdb_off).getConstantState())
        {
            botao.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rdb_on);
        }
        else
            botao.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rdb_off);
    }

});


holder.btnSim.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        ImageButton botaoSim = (ImageButton) arg0;

        if (botaoSim.getBackground().getConstantState()==getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rdb_off).getConstantState())
        {
            botaoSim.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rdb_on);
        }
        else
            botaoSim.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rdb_off);

    }

});
```

**EDIT** more of my code: http://pastebin.com/Jf1ZDek5

Comment: and what is the exact problem that your facing?

Comment: I have 2 onClickListeners but I need change in the same clickListener the btnSim and btnNao

Comment: Can't you move the variable declarations outside of the nested function so you can use them in both?

Answer (score 0):

**Notice the changes in the if{}.**

```
Button botao = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_1);
Button botaoSim = (Button) findViewById(r.id.button_2);
holder.btnNao.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    ImageButton botao = (ImageButton) arg0;

                    if (botao.getBackground().getConstantState()==getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rdb_off).getConstantState())
                    {
                        botao.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rdb_on);
                        botaoSim.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rdb_on);

                    }
                    else
                      botao.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rdb_off);
                }

            });


            holder.btnSim.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    ImageButton botaoSim = (ImageButton) arg0;

                    if (botaoSim.getBackground().getConstantState()==getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rdb_off).getConstantState())
                    {
                        botao.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rdb_on);
                        botaoSim.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rdb_on);
                    }
                    else
                        botaoSim.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rdb_off);

                }

            });
```

New code snippet

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (botaoSim.getBackground().getConstantState()==getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rdb_off).getConstantState())
                    {
                        botao.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rdb_on);
                        botaoSim.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rdb_on);
                    }
                    else
                        botaoSim.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rdb_off);
}


private class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
  /** All your implementations as in pastebin */
  ...
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    ViewHolder holder = null;
                    if (convertView == null) {
                            holder = new ViewHolder();
                            /* Add reference to holder.btnNao and holder.btnSim */
                            holder.btnNao.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
                            holder.btnSim.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
                            /* Your remaining code */
   }
}
```

Notice I have made customAdapter a private inner class in MainActivity.

Comment: I already have holder.btnSim and holder.btnNao outside clickListener but I have tried `else
        botaoSim.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rdb_off);
            holder.btnNao.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rdb_on);
    
      }` but Im getting error saying that holder must be final

Comment: Can you show more of your code ? From your use of holder, it looks like you are implementing the onClick in getView() of some adapter. More revelation of your code can help others to help you better.

Comment: Though this is not the best way to code, this should work for the above case.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the `onClickListener` since part of the two buttons do the same thing:

**Example:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        botao.setOnClickListener(this);
        botaoSim.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //put your code here.
    }
}
```